# template function in c++ want to return another container

Tags: c++, qt

I made this class but its fail in compile with this error:

> expected primary-expression at end of input

Why?

```
class ContextClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ContextClass(UnitOfWork u, QObject *parent = 0);

    template <class T> QList<T> table(const QString& filter = QString)
    {
        return QList<T>();
    }
};
```

Comment: problem was QString default value must be QString() sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
const QString& filter = QString
```

With:

```
const QString& filter = QString()
```